# FullCalendar JS - Events with the same start and end time aren't showing

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Here is the JSON of the events object that I'm using for this.

```
[{"id":"90797496757","title":"Event Slot #1 - 2","allDay":false,"start":"2020-02-01T07:00:00","end":"2020-02-01T09:00:00","rendering":"background"},{"id":"90797017323","title":"Event Slot #1 - 1","allDay":false,"start":"2020-02-01T07:00:00","end":"2020-02-01T09:00:00","rendering":"background"},{"id":"90798034365","title":"Event Slot #2 - 1","allDay":false,"start":"2020-02-01T11:00:00","end":"2020-02-01T13:00:00","rendering":"background"},{"id":"90798407481","title":"Event Slot #2 - 2","allDay":false,"start":"2020-02-01T11:00:00","end":"2020-02-01T13:00:00","rendering":"background"}]
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
Vue.config.devtools = true;
var ajaxurl = ajax_object.ajax_url;

var myApp = new Vue({
    el: "#front-end",
    data: {
        settings : {},
        updating : false,
        customerData : esp_data.customer_data,
        superPass : null,
        calendar : null,
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.setup();
    },
    methods: {
        setup: function() {
            this.superPass = this.customerData.super_passes[0];

            if (this.superPass.events.length > 0) {
                var events = this.superPass.events.map( function(event) {
                    return {
                        "id": event.id,
                        "title": event.name.text,
                        "allDay": false,
                        "start": event.start.local,
                        "end": event.end.local,
                        "rendering": "background",
                    }
                });
                console.log(JSON.stringify(events));

                var startDate = events[0].start;

                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('full-calendar');

                this.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    plugins: [ 'timeGrid' ],
                    defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
                    defaultDate: startDate,
                    events: events,
                });

                this.calendar.render();
            }

        }

    }
});
```

I have two sets of events with identical start and end times, but for some reason they won't show up on the calendar. However, when I set each event's allDay property as true, they show up no problem. Is there something I'm over looking/doing wrong?

Comment: You're specifying them as "background" events. A background event always takes up the entirety of its slot. So if you put two background events in the exact same slot  then you'll only ever see one of them (demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwYRbdM). I think the background event concept is intended just to let you highlight something global (e.g. days which are holidays, or something for example), it wasn't conceived as something where you need to overlay multiple things at the same time. What are you actually trying to use them to represent in this case?

Comment: P.S. I don't recognise "when I set each event's allDay property as true, they show up no problem"...that doesn't play out if you demo it...you just get one big blob of green over the whole day: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEYPKMG